# Removing meta from posts in wordpress (including posted by and icons )

Tags: wordpress, post, metadata

Hey I'm trying to remove publisher info and time it was published from post on wordpress. I had luck with actual data. but I  also would like to remove "posted by" and "posted date" and category: .  on the home page slider posts have icons of person and a clock.

[this is the full post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSxcX.png)

[and this icons show on front page post slider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzPX1.png)

single.php file:

```
 <?php
$post_sidebar_layout=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_post_sidebar_layout', true);
$sidebar_position = "right";
if($post_sidebar_layout == 'default'){
    $sidebar_position=th_theme_data('home_sidebar_position','right');
}elseif($post_sidebar_layout == 'fullwidth'){
    $sidebar_position = 'no';
}elseif($post_sidebar_layout == 'sidebar_left'){
    $sidebar_position = 'left';
}elseif($post_sidebar_layout == 'sidebar_right'){
    $sidebar_position = 'right';
}
if($sidebar_position == "no"){
    $page_class="col-lg-12 col-md-12";
}else{
    $page_class="col-lg-9";
}
if($sidebar_position == "left"){
    $page_class .=' pull-right';
}
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="i-blog-section-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($page_class); ?>">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                <div class="i-blog-title">
                    <h1><?php the_title()?></h1>
                </div>              

                <div>
                    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <div <?php post_class()?> >
                            <?php
                            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                            wp_link_pages('before=<div id="page-links">&after=</div>'); ?>
                            <p class="post-tags">
                                <span><?php esc_html_e('Categories:', 'larx'); ?> </span><?php the_category(', '); ?>
                            </p>
                            <?php th_blog_post_tags(); ?> 
                            <?php if (th_theme_data('switch_social_share') == 1){ ?>
                                <div class="share-options">                                    
                                    <h6><?php esc_html_e("Share this post: ", 'larx'); ?></h6>
                                    <a href="" class="twitter-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('twitterSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="facebook-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('facebookSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="pinterest-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('pinterestSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="google-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('googleSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="delicious-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('deliciousSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-share fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                    <a href="" class="linkedin-sharer" onClick="<?php echo esc_js('linkedinSharer()'); ?>"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></a>
                                </div>                               
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if (th_theme_data('switch_about_author') == 1){ ?>
                                <div class="blog-author">
                                    <hr>
                                    <h3><?php echo __('About the Author', 'larx')?></h3>
                                    <div class="author-img">
                                        <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'130')?>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>
                                        <?php echo get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'job',true)?>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php if($th_facebook_id=get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'facebook_url',true)):?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($th_facebook_id); ?>"><i class="fa  fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                        <?php if($th_twitter_id=get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'twitter_url',true)):?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($th_twitter_id); ?>"><i class="fa  fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                        <?php if($th_google_id=get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'google_plus_url',true)):?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($th_google_id); ?>"><i class="fa  fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" ></i></a>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php comments_template(); ?> 
                            <?php if (th_theme_data('switch_next_prev') == 1){ ?>
                                <div class="pager">
                                    <?php
                                    echo previous_post_link('%link','<button type="button" class="btn gold-btn" style="float:left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> '.esc_html_x('Older', 'older', 'larx').'</button>');
                                    echo next_post_link('%link','<button type="button" class="btn gold-btn" style="float:right">'.esc_html_x('Newer', 'newer', 'larx').' <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div><!-- single-post-wrapper -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php if($sidebar_position!="no"){ ?>
                <div id="sidebar" class="col-lg-3">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div><!-- end sidebar -->
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you'd have to dig on the theme file, they are displayed there because single.php or whatever hooks place them in there

Comment: hey. So this is what my single.php looks like . Ill add the code in desc

Comment: It's probably in multiple theme files. Check `content.php` or one of the sidebar files for the ones that appear on individual posts. You may have a template part like `slider.php` for the homepage slider, or possibly `front-page.php` or `home.php`, it just depends on how it was coded.

Comment: hey. ty. Is this it?  this was in content.php

<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Published by', 'larx' ); ?>

    <a rel="author" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url(
 get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
    </a>
</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo esc_html_e(' Posted on', 'larx'); ?>
    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
</p>
<?php the_content(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the published by and date from content.php file. But make sure to not delete the last line of code in that file